# SUMIF date range and filter by value on Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

How do I `SUMIF` two date ranges and filter with a value? The date range formula I've been using is:

```
=sumif($A:$A,"<="&D$5,$C:$C)-sumif($A:$A,"<"&D$4,$C:$C)
```

Which works great for summing all values within column C. But as my sheet gets larger it would be nice to add a value filter, which in this example is (D6:) Food

```
Column A     Column B   Column C      Column D 
7/25/2012    Food       $9.26                                      
7/25/2012    Clothes    $40.00        D4 = Start Date (7/16/2012)
7/24/2012    Fast Food  $10.00        D5 = End Date   (7/20/2012)       
7/21/2012    Gas        $471.50    D6 = Value      (Food)       
7/18/2012    Food       $3.60          Sum of results = $516.49    
7/23/2012    Food       $478.73 
7/23/2012    Food       $34.16  
7/16/2012    Gas        $82.33  
7/15/2012    Food       $74.00 
7/15/2012    Rent       $400.00
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here's the answer for reference:

`=sum(filter(A:A,C2:C16=$D$6,A2:A>=D4,A2:A16<=D2))`

Comment: You apply the string filter to Column C. That must be Column B. The first argument of the `FILTER` function is the range it needs to filter. In your case that must be Column C.

Answer (score 7):

In order to reproduce the result, given by the OP, you need to use this formula.

### Formula

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C,B2:B=D6,A2:A>=D4,A2:A<=D5))
```

### Note

Apart from that, you need to change the end date from `7/20/2012` to `7/23/2012`

### Screenshot

[image]

### Example

See example file I prepared: **[SUM with FILTER](https://docs.google.com/a/familietuinstra.nl/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdGdveDNPZ0JkRUI3MVplY3lxOHRLcUE&usp=sharing)**